# Соглашение об именовании типов

Tags: golang, архитектура, namespace

Каким образом следует именовать интерфейсы в golang?

Пусть у меня есть клиент к БД (или сервису):

```
type BaseMongo interface {
    Read(ctx context.Context, filter bson.M, db string, collection string, out interface{}) error
}
```

А также, есть сам клиент

```
type Mongo struct {
    client *mongo.Client
}

func (m *Mongo) Read(ctx context.Context, filter bson.M, db string, collection string, out interface{}) error {
    return m.client.Database(db).Collection(collection).FindOne(context.Background(), filter).Decode(out)
}
```

Как следует назвать интерфейс, а как назвать сам объект? `BaseMongo` -- название плохое, покуда не отражает сути типа. Возможно, интерфейс стоит переименовать как `Mongo`, а объект назвать иначе.

Comment: так же полезно : https://habr.com/ru/articles/441842/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу однометодных интерфейсов написано в [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface-names):

> By convention, one-method interfaces are named by the method name plus an -er suffix or similar modification to construct an agent noun: `Reader`, `Writer`, `Formatter`, `CloseNotifier` etc.

Так что если ваш интерфейс имеет только метод `Read`, вы можете назвать его `MongoReader` или `mongo.Reader`, если ваш пакет называется `mongo`.

В ином случае лучше придерживаться смысла интерфейса. Если он абстрагирует клиент или сервис, то и назвать следует `MongoClient` или `MongoService`.

Comment: Сделал `BaseMongo` -> `Storage`. `Mongo` -> `Mongo`